# Relating Task to Multiple Accounts

Tags: account, activities, shared-activities

Is it possible to relate a task to multiple accounts? I am not wanting to relate to multiple contacts within accounts. I want to pull agreement information into salesforce, and the relationship is with the account, not the contact.

I am making the relationships in SQL and pushing into SF.

Would it be possible to [use the EventRelation object in connection with tasks?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hUp8AAE) I could fill in the [eventid, accountid, iswhat, and maybe the relationid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) (if needed). I am building that out now to test.

Is it possible to create a junction object for the many to many relationship? I have one built and tried to make a lookup relationship to the task, but it appears that tasks cannot be parent objects. Or am I perhaps missing something?

I really do not desire to create multiple lookup fields to the account. The end goal is to be able to include these activities in reports based on each account. Would I just have to bite the bullet and build joined reports with these "activities" on a custom object?

Comment: Perhaps from the task perspective the relationship is not directly with the accounts you mention, but in fact the agreement that the task must be actioned against ? Could you thus relate tasks to the agreement, and then the agreement to one or more accounts ?

Comment: Tasks can not be the parent of any object. The `Task` is meant to be a "to-do" for some "who" (user, contact, lead) related to some "what" (Opportunity, Quote, Contract, Account, Case)

Comment: @CloudHugger I thought about that, too, but that would still require a junction object, would it not? And it would need a custom object for the agreements, which I already have built out. Honestly, I just want to be able to include these records in reports with the activities in a simple straight forward way.

Comment: Ok- so consider adding an account lookup field onto the task record. When a task is linked via whatid to an agreement, populate the account lookup with account that agreement is linked to (via trigger logic).Then you can report on accounts with tasks that relate to agreements, or agreement specific tasks grouped by account. Is that what you want ?